# Array in php formarting

Tags: php, arrays, json

I’m having issues with an array in PHP. I create an array, it’s good, but in order to see it I use `json_encode`. See examples below.

Original array:

```
Array (
        [0] => Array ( [0] => GCXO )
        [1] => Array ( [0] => LEAS )
        [2] => Array ( [0] => LECO )
      )
```

I get this:

```
[["GCXO"],["LEAS"],["LECO"]]
```

I want this:

```
["GCXO", "LEAS", "LECO"]
```

The problem is that if I don’t use `json_encode` it returns the word `array`.

Does anyone knows how to get that result?

Comment: please show your code please.

Comment: Absolutely not clear what you want. Show what you put in and what you expect to come out.

Comment: Edited the question with the examples

Comment: First you say you need this `(value1,value2,value3,...)` then later you say this `["london", "brussels", "prague", "athens",`.  Which is it?  And what does the original array look like?

Comment: Now yes! Edited :)

Comment: @AbraCadaver it gives me [["GCXO"],["LEAS"],["LECO"],

Comment: This is the array: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => GCXO
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => LEAS
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => LECO
        )

Comment: Only if what you have posted is NOT correct https://3v4l.org/cpHeO

Comment: Yes, did you give up or have more input or something helped you?

Answer (score 2):

If the JSON shows `[["GCXO"],["LEAS"],["LECO"]]` then you have a multi-dimensional array and need to flatten it to get `["GCXO", "LEAS", "LECO"]`:

```
echo json_encode(array_merge(...$array));
```

Comment: it gives me [["GCXO"],["LEAS"],["LECO"]

Comment: NO https://3v4l.org/cpHeO

Answer (score 1):

When you use json_encode, you are in fact converting the array to a JSON object, its **not longer** an "array".

If you only want to see the content of the array, you can use:

```
print_r($array)
```

or, you can format it as you like with a loop accessing it values with $array[*iterator*]

Also you can iterate trough it with `foreach`, giving it the format that you need.

```
foreach($array as $object){
    echo ','.$object;
}
```

for example

Comment: You can use echo separating multiple arguments by comma. No need to create a concatenated string before.

Answer (score -1):

use function `implode(',', $array);`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Take note that the OP wants JSON output.